# Need to return sum of score more than 60 where is score is an element inside an array JSON objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Documents which I have in my MongoDB collection are like below and the length of the array ***grades*** of JSON objects is varying:

```
{
"address": {
    "building": "1007",
    "coord": [-73.856077, 40.848447],
    "street": "Morris Park Ave",
    "zipcode": "10462"
},
"borough": "Bronx",
"cuisine": "Bakery",
"grades": [{
    "date": {
        "$date": 1393804800000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 2
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1378857600000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 6
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1358985600000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 10
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1322006400000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 9
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1299715200000
    },
    "grade": "B",
    "score": 14
}],
"name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
"restaurant_id": "30075445"
}

{
"address": {
    "building": "469",
    "coord": [-73.961704, 40.662942],
    "street": "Flatbush Avenue",
    "zipcode": "11225"
},
"borough": "Brooklyn",
"cuisine": "Hamburgers",
"grades": [{
    "date": {
        "$date": 1419897600000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 8
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1404172800000
    },
    "grade": "B",
    "score": 23
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1367280000000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 12
}, {
    "date": {
        "$date": 1336435200000
    },
    "grade": "A",
    "score": 12
}],
"name": "Wendy'S",
"restaurant_id": "30112340"
}
```

The task is to write a MongoDB query to return the collections which are having the sum of scores greater than 60.

Comment: Can you show your code of what you have done ?

Comment: Put some effort on what you are trying to achieve. If you are stuck somewhere we will be happy to help you. Nobody will write code for you here.

Comment: Hi Shrabanee, I tried and a lot failed to find the solution. That's I have asked on this forum. If you can help just do it or else leave it. Don't think you are an Einstein. You said you will help.. I've clearly explained the question, now you post some solution without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this can be done:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$grades" // flatten the "grades" array
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "sumOfScores": { // calculate the sum of all grades for all documents with the same "_id"
            $sum: "$grades.score"
        },
        "docs": {
            $push: "$$ROOT" // remember all affected documents per group
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "sumOfScores": {
            $gt: 60 // filter out everything that we don't care about
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten the "docs" array
},  {
    $group: { // restore the original document structure
        "_id": "$docs._id",
        "address": { $first: "$docs.address" },
        "borough": { $first: "$docs.borough" },
        "cuisine": { $first: "$docs.cuisine" },
        "grades": {
            $push: "$docs.grades"
        },
        "name": { $first: "$docs.name" },
        "restaurant_id": { $first: "$docs.restaurant_id" }
    }
})
```